# Elements fixed when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently trying to get the subnav to stick when scrolled to a certain position. But when it gets to that position everything below it moves up. Cant quite figure out what it is. could be very simple and I'm just not seeing it. Thanks for the help

CSS

```
#subnav ul{
list-style: none;
}
#subnav a:visited{
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
}
#subnav a{
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
}
#subnav.fixed{
position:fixed;
top:0;
}
.main {
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:10px;
border-top-left-radius:10px;
border-top-right-radius:10px;
min-height: 500px;
height: auto;
width: 700px;
-moz-box-shadow:    -1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
box-shadow:         -1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
float: none;
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
z-index:1000;
    position: relative;
font-size: 12px;
background-color: #FFF;
background-position: left top;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
margin-bottom: -200px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="subnav">
        <ul>
            content
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="imageholder">
            content
        </div>

        <div class="text">
            content
        </div>
    </div>

$(document).ready(function () {  
var top = $('#subnav').offset().top -    parseFloat($('#subnav').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
// what the y position of the scroll is
var y = $(this).scrollTop();

// whether that's below the form
if (y >= top) {
  // if so, ad the fixed class
  $('#subnav').addClass('fixed');
} else {
  // otherwise remove it
  $('#subnav').removeClass('fixed');
}
});
});
```

Comment: are you saying that the content seems to 'jump' up when the scrollbar goes from `static` to `fixed` positioning?

Comment: You need to set a custom class for the docking at the bottom part, at least that's what I am using, if it's not on top and not fixed, add this margin-top and make it dock the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question was asked 1.5 years ago, but I'm answering anyway in case it can help someone in the future...

I recently ran into this same issue while working on a site.  Like Daniel said, it's jumping up because you are removing the `#subnav` from the flow, which is what setting the position to 'fixed' does.  It's essentially doing the same thing as if you were to remove your `#subnav` element altogether:  jumping up to fill the gap.

To remedy this, when scrolling to that point where it becomes fixed I created a new div with all of the same dimensions, padding, margins, etc, to essentially 'fill in' while the `#subnav` is fixed.  You can do this several ways: create a duplicate hidden div with a different ID that you show/hide when adding/removing the "fixed" class, or by dynamically creating one on the fly using JS.  Whatever your fix-of-choice is here, this will prevent the jumping issue.

Example:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (y >= top) {
      $('#subnav').addClass('fixed')
        .after("<div id='filler'></div>");    // Add the new "filler" div

      // Make the height, width, padding-top, padding-bottom, margin-top, and
      // margin-bottom the same as the #subnav
      $('#filler')
          .css("height", $('#subnav').css("height"))
          .css("width", $('#subnav').css("width"));    // etc

    } else {
      $('#subnav').removeClass('fixed');

      // Remove the filler
      $('#filler').remove();    // Or you can hide and show it again as needed
    }
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

the rest moves up because you are taking the #subnav out of the inline-flow.